# How can I set the Policy parameter in the authorization URL with knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, symfony-3.4

I am using
Symfony 3.4
and knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle (v1.34.0)
with the client library thenetworg/oauth2-azure (v1.4.2) to connect to an Azure AD B2C App.

When I initiate an authorization request, the generated URL has this form : https://blablabla.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize, followed by several parameters, one of them being for the policy :
p=b2c_1_signupin/{tenant_name}/oauth2/authorize

When I compare this generated URL with the URL given by our client, I can see that this p-parameter for the policy isn't correct, it should be :
p=b2c_1_signupin

How can I set the correct parameter for the policy ?

After lots of trial/errors my actual config in the config.yml is :

```
knpu_oauth2_client:
    clients:
        azure:
            type: azure
            client_id: '%OAUTH_AZURE_CLIENT_ID%'
            client_secret: '%OAUTH_AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET%'
            redirect_route: connect_azure_check
            redirect_params: { }
            url_login: 'https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1_signupin/'
            tenant: '%OAUTH_AZURE_TENANT_NAME%'
            url_api: 'https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/'
            api_version: '1.6'
```

The resulting policy parameter actually appends after the policy name the tenant_name and the path_authorize ('oauth2/authorize')

`p=b2c_1_signupin/{tenant_name}/{path_authorize}`

With this parameter, I get the error message : The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

To be working, the policy parameter should however be only
`p={policy_name}`, i.e. `p=b2c_1_signupin` without the appended {tenant_name} and {path_authorize}

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-authentication-requests

You don’t need to use query parameters for the policy Id. It’s supported as part of the authority:

```html
GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6
&response_type=code+id_token
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F
&response_mode=fragment
&scope=openid%20offline_access%20{application-id-uri}/{scope-name}
&state=arbitrary_data_you_can_receive_in_the_response
&nonce=12345
```

Comment: thx for your reply.
My problem is lies within the use of the knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle, who generates the GET Request. That's why I have to figure out how to configure this specific Symfony bundle.